# Как реализовать счетчик нажатий на кнопку в телеграм боте

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, aiogram

Надо сделать счетчик нажатий на keyboard кнопку, тоесть..
Допустим есть кнопка "пробный тест нажатия" юзер нажимает и бот просить написать ему что-то, юзер написал бот отвечает "Ура, у вас получилось!" и когда юзер нажимает повторный раз на кнопку, то бот отвечает "Попытка нажатия исчерпана"
то есть надо задать параметр боту чтобы у юзера была только одна попытка нажать кнопку..
Подскажите, пожалуйста.. Заранее Спасибо!

Comment: Уведомление о нажатии на кнопку вам придёт в любом случае. Вы можете сохранять количество нажатий на кнопку для каждого пользователя, ориентируясь на его ID. И в обработчике проверять, что у пользователя нет нажатий на кнопку

Comment: Спасибо, можете показать пример кода ? Буду благодарен !

Comment: Пример чего именно вы хотите увидеть? Если пока не понятно, к чему приступить, то найдите по отдельности, как: 1) Написать обработчик нажатия на кнопку; 2) Получить ID пользователя; 3) Создать словарь

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так.

```
user_dicts = {}

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda message: message.text=="button")
def button_1(message):
    if not user_dicts.get(message.from_user.id):
        user_dicts[message.from_user.id] = 1
    else:
        user_dicts[message.from_user.id] += 1
        
    bot.send_message(
        message.chat.id, 
        f"Кнопка нажата {user_dicts[message.from_user.id]} раз.")


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(
        message.chat.id,
        "text",
        reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(
            InlineKeyboardButton('Кнопка', callback_data='button')))
```